The function 'orch_fun' doesn't exist, is disabled, or is not an orchestrator func. Additional info:No orchestrator functions are currently registered
I'm trying to create an Async HTTP Api with Azure Durable Functions and Python.
But I get the below mentioned error:
The function 'orchestrator_function' doesn't exist, is disabled,
or is not an orchestrator function. Additional info: No orchestrator functions are currently registered!

I have created a dir for the orchestrator function and a dir for the activiry function. Each of these directories have a __init__.py and a function.json file.
The client function is one dir/level up and is being called successfully by the pipeline which is supposed to call it.
host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:30:00",
  "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
          "Function.kati_function_app.User": "Information",
          "Function.health-check": "Error"
        }
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0]"
  }
}

Project structure:
     .
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── host.json
├── pipeline
│   ├── pipeline.yml
│   └── templates
│       ├── deploy.yml
│       ├── run.yml
│       └── variables.yml
├── requirements.txt
└── some_dir
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── activity_function
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── function.json
    ├── client_function (empty dir)
    ├── function.json
    ├── orchestrator_function
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── function.json
    ├── settings.ini
    ├── settings_local.ini

How/where do I register an orchestrator function while working with Python v1
 

I realized that when the orchestration_function is two levels deeper than the base directory/project then it's not discoverable.
This structure did the trick for me:
.
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── activity_function
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── function.json
├── client_function
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── function.json
├── host.json
├── orchestrator_function
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── function.json
├── pipeline
│   ├── pipeline.yml
│   └── templates
│       ├── deploy.yml
│       ├── run.yml
│       └── variables.yml
├── requirements.txt
└── some_dir
    ├── __init__.py
    └── helper_functions.py


